# What will happen if a 'roscore' has already been run when I run a launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What will happen if a `roscore` has already been run when I run a launch file?
Does the roslaunch override the old `roscore`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197769/what-will-happen-if-a-%27roscore%27-has-already-been-run-when-i-run-a-launch-file?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nothing spectacular: `roslaunch` will detect that a `roscore` instance is already running and use that (instead of starting a new one).

From the [roscore](http://wiki.ros.org/roscore) wiki page:

> NOTE: If you use roslaunch, it will automatically start `roscore` if it detects that it is not already running.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3